# addClass to <tr> depence of <td> value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, addclass

Bootstrap offers a `.danger` class. I want to add this class if the last `<td>` has a value greater than or equal to 0.

My Table looks similar to this one:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>#</th>
   <th>Timestamp</th>
   <th>Failures</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>  
   <th>1</th>
   <td>date</td>
   <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
   <th>2</th>
   <td>date</td>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("table tbody tr").each(function () {
    var cell = $(this).find("td:last-child").text();

   if ($(this).val()>='0') tr.addClass('danger');       
    else tr.removeClass('danger');
    }
});
})
```

I think the problem is in getting the value from the `<td>`. Or that jQuery expects a class for the `<td>` permanently written and change from that class to a different one.

Comment: `tr` is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Changes*

1. You need to use current element i.e. `this` in place of `tr`
2. Use `.text()` to get the text as `TD` element doesn't have `value` 
   properties
3. For numerical comparison convert the text into appropriate date type. Here in example I have use `parseInt()`.

*Code*

```
$("table tbody tr").each(function() {

   //Read text then it to number
   var cell = parseInt($(this).find("td:last").text(), 10);
   if (cell > 0) {
       $(this).addClass('danger'); //use current element
   } else {
       $(this).removeClass('danger'); //use current element
   }

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tbody tr").each(function() {

    //Parse text to number
    var cell = parseInt($(this).find("td:last").text(), 10);
    if (cell > 0)
      $(this).addClass('danger'); //use context selector this
    else
      $(this).removeClass('danger'); //use context selector this

  });
})
```

```css
.danger {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
      <th>Failures</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>date</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes.

1. using val() instead of text
2. tr is undefined. Assign $(this) to tr

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("table tbody tr").each(function () {
    var cell = $(this).find("td:last-child").text();
    var tr = $(this);

   if (parseFloat($(this).text())>=0) //notice, I have used parseFloat to parse the number
      tr.addClass('danger');       
   else tr.removeClass('danger');
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use  logical operation like `>=` do not use the value in `" "` because the operations just works with numbers.

```
if ($(this).val()>=0) tr.addClass('danger');       
    else tr.removeClass('danger');
    }
```